# Dragging annotations to the left edge is causing issues

Tags: highcharts

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/n21kofx9/15/), where I can draw annotations and drag them around.

But, in case I draw a `segment` or `arrow-segment` and in case I try to drag them to the most left edge of the chart, they are changing it's position and are aligning vertically and parallelly to the left edge. The demo can be seen [in this video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crVo6l9V3i).

I tested and concluded that the issue has nothing to do with the plugins which I am having in the code I posted. So I wonder if this is a highcharts bug or if this behavior can be fixed within the `onDrag` event?

```
H.wrap(H.Annotation.prototype, 'onDrag', function(proceed) {  
  var annotation = this;
  proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  //do something here?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug, I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14944

Setting `ordinal=false` resolves the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cnosa15L/1/